# A parition induced on $A$ by $f^{-1}(Y_1),f^{-1}(Y_2),...,f^{-1}(Y_n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, set-partition

The following thought just occured to me on my way back home i forgot it for some while but now i remembered it again is the argument below correct?

> **Proposition**. Lets say that we have a surjective map $f:A\to B$ where $A$ and $B$
>   are aritrary sets. In addition we have the subsets sets
>   $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ such that they determine a partition over the set
>   $B$. Does it then follows that the sets
>   $f^{-1}(Y_1),f^{-1}(Y_2),...,f^{-1}(Y_n)$ determine a partion over the
>   set $A$.

I think that the answer is yes and the following is my attempt at a proof is it correct?

*Proof.* Let $I_n = \{1,2,...,n\}.$ We first prove that $A = \bigcup_{i\in I_n}f^{-1}(Y_i)$. Assume that $a\in A$ consequently $f(a)\in B$ since $B = \bigcup_{i\in I_n}Y_i$ it follows that for some $j\in I_n$ it must be that $f(a)\in Y_j$ equivalently $a\in f^{-1}(Y_j)$ and by implication $a\in\bigcup_{i\in I_n}f^{-1}(Y_i)$. The converse is evident from the fact that $\bigcup_{i\in I_n}f^{-1}(Y_i)$ is in fact a union of subsets of $A$.

We now prove that $f^{-1}(Y_1),f^{-1}(Y_2),...,f^{-1}(Y_n)$ are pairwise disjoint. Assume that for some $i,j\in I_n$ we have $f^{-1}(Y_i)\cap f^{-1}(Y_j)\neq \varnothing$  where $i\neq j$. Since $f^{-1}(Y_i)\cap f^{-1}(Y_j)\neq \varnothing$ we may invoke a $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)\in Y_i\cap Y_j$ but $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ constitute a partition of $B$ and are therefore pairwise disjoint resulting in a contradiction.

Finally since $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ is partition it follows that $Y_i\neq\varnothing$ which taken together with the surjectivity of $f$ implies that for some $a\in A$ we have $f(a)=b\in Y_i$ equivalently $a\in f^{-1}(Y_i)$ thus $f^{-1}(Y_i)\neq\varnothing$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Looks correct and also, I don't see why your proof wouldn't work for infinite partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but some details could have been avoided.

Note that  $$B= \cup Y_i$$  thus $$A = \bigcup_{i\in I_n}f^{-1}(Y_i)$$

because $x\in f^{-1}(Y_i)$ for some $Y_i$

Also $$ f^{-1}(Y_i)\cap f^{-1}(Y_j) =\phi $$ because $f:A\to B$ is a function.